# Mysql query to fetch sum from table

Tags: mysql

I would like to perform mathematical operations along with fetching records from table.

Example : I have table with below data

```
| orderid | value | orderdate    |
 ----------------------------------
  1       | 100   |  2013-08-08  | 
  2       | 200   |  2013-08-05  | 
  3       | 300   |  2013-08-06  | 
  4       | 400   |  2013-08-09  |
```

And I am looking to sum(value) along with fetching all records from table. Example output

```
sum(value)| orderid | value | orderdate    |
 -------------------------------------------
  1000    | 1       | 100   |  2013-08-08  | 
  1000    | 2       | 200   |  2013-08-05  | 
  1000    | 3       | 300   |  2013-08-06  | 
  1000    | 4       | 400   |  2013-08-09  |
```

Comment: Please note 1000 is sum of value of all fetched records.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `CROSS JOIN`.

```
SELECT  b.TotalValue, a.*
FROM    tableName a
        CROSS JOIN 
        (SELECT SUM(value) totalValue FROM tableName) b
```

or a correlated subquery,

```
SELECT  (SELECT SUM(value) FROM tableName) totalValue, 
        a.*
FROM    tableName a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT a.*,SUM(b.value) FROM tablename AS a,tablename AS b GROUP BY a.orderid
```